# Price input formatter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, price

I'm trying to write the code for price input. The task should be simple, but something doesn't work..
I have a Vue project and I need user to enter the price in input field, where the price should be filling form the last char. Example: start value "00.00"; when user enter "1" then value became "00.01", when user add "4" then value became "00.14", when add 2 then "01.42".

The code is kind of works, but just inputted number staying in input field, even if I add  `event.target.value = ""`;

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    price: '00.00'
  },
  methods: {
    handleKeyDown(event) {
      const key = event.key;
      const validKeys = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];

      if (!validKeys.includes(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
      }

      const newPrice = this.price.replace('.', '') + key;
      const parsedPrice = parseFloat(newPrice);

      if (isNaN(parsedPrice) || parsedPrice > 9999) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
      }

      const priceWithDecimal = (parsedPrice / 100).toFixed(2);
      this.price = "0" + priceWithDecimal;
      //   event.target.value = "";
      console.log(this.price);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="price" @keydown="handleKeyDown">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `watch` the `price` value for changes instead.

```js
const
  parseValue  = (v) => parseInt(v.trim().replace(/\./g, ''), 10),
  formatValue = (v) => (v / 100).toFixed(2).replace(/^(\d)(?=\.)/, '0$1');

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    price: '00.00'
  },
  watch: {
    price(newValue, oldValue) {
      const parsed = parseValue(newValue);
      this.price = !isNaN(parsed) ? formatValue(parsed) : oldValue;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="number" v-model="price" step="0.01">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works well! Couldn't find the answer anywhere! Chat GPT helpless. Googling also didn't give me any help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel.

MDN: [<input type="number">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    price: 0
  },
  watch: {
    price(val) {
      this.price = Math.round(val * 100) / 100;
    }    
  },
  computed: {
    priceFormated() {
      return this.price.toLocaleString('en-US',
      {
          style:"currency", 
          currency:"USD",
          minimumIntegerDigits: 2,
          useGrouping: false
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="price" type="number" placeholder="1.0" step="0.01" min="0" max="10" /><br/>
  <button @click="price -= 1">-1</button>
  Price: {{priceFormated}}
  <button @click="price += 1">+1</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Run previous code snippet and see what is the difference between your and his. I need his "wheel" ;D